# Pointer moving randomly [Touchscreen TFT]

Tags: touchscreen, pitft, pygame

My 320x240 2.8" PiTFT (#1601) reached me yesterday. I install Jessie-based PiTFT 2.4" and 2.8" Resistive Image for Pi 1 and Pi 2 (September 24, 2015) image to my sdcard. At first everything seems perfect. I can see hdmi output on my screen. Both console and desktop environment seems perfect. Then I tried touch thing, it seems perfect too (tested it desktop environment, and console with ts_test).

After that, i want to try pygame for gui, and I realize, cursor going crazy. Not just a calibration problem, pointer moves around randomly, even when I don't move my sytlus. Here is a video of that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AgkgpnXc6k

And my code: https://gist.github.com/yozel/679b331570f0dc5d45eb

What's going on? What have i done wrong?

Comment: I have the same behaviour. The PiTFT works well with the X interface, the calibration software but it doesn't work on console : GPM or pygame.

Comment: is there any support from adafruit for gpm support ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing Wheezy instead of Jessie:

I had the same problem on the 2.8" capacitive TFT after upgrading Raspbian to Jessie; but it runs ok with latest Wheezy release.

Comment: I have tried this just now and it works! Really, really thank you!

Comment: what files changed ? how to make it work on jessie ?